# How to move a question to a different site without migration privileges?

Tags: support, migration

I've asked a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15008/aperture-and-itunes-freezing-bringing-down-snow-leopard-entirely) here that has gotten very little response, and I think it would do better on superuser.com.  First, am I right?  If so, how do I go about moving it, since I don't have the rep to migrate?  I've considered posting a duplicate (which I've [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205124/security-for-data-produced-by-asp-net-web-serivce) [before](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80925/security-for-data-produced-by-asp-net-web-serivce)), or putting something like "(please migrate to super user)" in the title.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like something migrated, you can flag it for moderator attention - it's the "flag" link directly under the tags for the post. If you'd like, I can move your question to Super User, but it might yet get an answer here. I don't personally mind people cross-posting questions, especially if they haven't gotten a response on a particular site, but not everyone agrees with that.

So I guess it's up to you - I don't mind if you crosspost, but if you want I'll migrate it for you instead.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the title to include "please migrate to super user" is probably the less effective way to get a question migrated to another site.

I would flag the question, and report I think it better suits the other site.
As alternative, I would ask the question in the other site; in that case, I would probably close the question on Ask Different, if it has not answers, or flag the question and report you already asked the question in another SE site.